# Changing multiple elements with on mouse hover and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How can I get all the elements within a wrap to change color when mouse hovers on the cube in http://codepen.io/Feners4/pen/KggAwg? Currently, I can only get it to change on a single side the mouse hover on. I want to do this strictly with Angular for learning purposes.

This is my HTML:

```
<html>

<header>
  Angularity
</header>

<h1>hjskl</hi>

<body ng-app="App">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube"change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>
        <div class="front" change-background>AAA</div>
        <div class="back" change-background></div>
        <div class="top" change-background></div>
        <div class="bottom" change-background></div>
        <div class="left" change-background></div>
        <div class="right" change-background></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="cube2">
        <div class="front2" change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>AAA</div>
        <div class="back2" change-background ></div>
        <div class="top2" change-background></div>
        <div class="bottom2" change-background></div>
        <div class="left2" change-background></div>
        <div class="right2" change-background></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS:

```
angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('changeBackground', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        colorcode: '@?'
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
          element.addClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
          element.removeClass('change-color');
          element.css('background-color', '@red');
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is add your directive to the parent of the cube sides, then inside use `.children()` to apply your function to each child item. Also you will want to have your class `change-color` to be general as in have not `:foo`, otherwise the CSS will still only apply to the hovered element even if they all have the class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="cube" change-background colorcode=¨#f45642¨>
        <div class="front" >AAA</div>
        <div class="back" ></div>
        <div class="top" ></div>
        <div class="bottom" ></div>
        <div class="left" ></div>
        <div class="right" ></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap2">
    <div class="cube2" change-background>
        <div class="front2"  colorcode=¨#f45642¨>AAA</div>
        <div class="back2"></div>
        <div class="top2"></div>
        <div class="bottom2"></div>
        <div class="left2"></div>
        <div class="right2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  link: function($scope, element, attr) {
    element.on('mouseenter', function() {
      element.children().addClass('change-color');
      element.children().css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
    });
    element.on('mouseleave', function() {
      element.children().removeClass('change-color');
      element.children().css('background-color', '@red');
    });
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.change-color {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f45642;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**Pen Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgBdPA)

Comment: @feners No problem. I actually didn't notice that's what you where wanting from your last question.